# Curity SCIM group endpoint

Tags: scim, curity

It is mentioned on their doc [here](https://curity.io/resources/learn/managing-users-with-scim/#create)

> It would also be possible to create a group in the same way but then define the group schema instead of the user schema.

However, it seems `um-api` can only be used for below purposed and it is mentioned [here](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/user-management-admin-guide/defining-user-management-profile.html).

> `um-api`: a SCIM 2.0-like API which allows access to Users, Devices and Delegations

Does anyone know how to use create groups and associate groups with users using Curity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no `Groups` endpoint in the user management profile. However, if the underlying datasource is a LDAP group, and responds with a `memberOf` attribute, it will be translated into the scim `groups` multivalued attribute.
Typically, groups are handled outside of Curity.

Comment: Thanks @dlindau for your reply, this means I wasted a good few hours trying to solve a non-existing issue... Anyway, may I suggest Curity to consider removing `It would be possible to create a group in the same way` part from your doc because users can not add a group the same way they add users. Or at least putting a reference about this function only works with LDAP or other OIDC providers.